# Source for various pictures in 120x120?

Tags: authentication, image

I am creating a web site with 2-stage authentication where users will have to verify a particular image on the screen (similar to how many banks and CC companies are currently doing this).

Where can I find a large source of images (not icons) that are about 120x120 (or larger) for use in this? Ideally, Id like to find a few hundred of these images and they do not have to be free.

Comment: http://www.google.com/images?q=funny.  But seriously, just take any collection you like and scale/crop it down to 120x120.  There should be plenty of royalty-free stock images out there, if that's what you want to start with.

Comment: *20* questions and less than 1/6th have accepted answers?  See the comments at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830896/.

Answer (score 1):

You could search for Creative-Commons photos available for commercial use on flickr: http://www.flickr.com/search/?q=nature&l=comm&ss=0&ct=0&mt=all&w=all&adv=1

Answer (score 0):

I've used [freedigitalphotos.net](http://www.freedigitalphotos.net) in the past to get some pretty good images -- you can get the small ones (about 640x480) for free.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's Google's image search, the options let you specify the exact dimensions you're after, and they'll search most stock-photo/art sites, too.

Answer (score 0):

[iStockPhoto](http://istockphoto.com/) sells stock photography, you can just buy the lower rez stuff.